# CSS - how to place div using z-index?

Tags: css, html, stylesheet

I have a short question on how to place a div class.

I have two error layers with some error messages that I would like to echo out. for each of this error message layer I have a div class:

```
.wrapper #header #navline form .errol {
    color: #F23;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 26px;
    padding:8px; 
    display: inline;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    line-height: 26px;
    right: 100%;
    top: 8%;
}
.wrapper #header #navline form .errol2 {
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 26px;
    padding:8px; 
    display: inline;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    line-height: 26px;
    right: 100%;
    top: 28%;
}
```

The problem is that when using `top`and `right` the position is fixed. at another place I use for the same task instead of `top`and `right` I'll use `margin-left` and `margin-top` where I do not have the following problem:

php echoes different error messages with different string lengths. When using `margin-left` and `margin-top`only margin-top works fine. margin-left will be positioned wrong because the div will extended to both sides. So what I would like to know is if there is a way to fix the right hand side to a fixed position so that the div will be extended left hand side only?

So if anybody could help me out I would really appreciate.

UPDATE:

To show some images what I mean.

this is like it should be:
[image: this is how it should be]

and this happens when the string length grows:
[image: this happens when the string length extends]

UPDATE2:

To give some HTML code:

```
<div class="small">
    <?php if (empty($errors['xxx']) === false){?>
        <input class="log-err" type="text" id="xxx" placeholder="xxx" name="xxx" value="<?php echo isset($xxx) ? $xxx : '';?>" />
        <div class='error'>
            <?php echo $errors['xxx'][0];?>
        </div>
    <?php }else{?>
        <input type="text" id="xxx" name="xxx" placeholder="xxx" value="<?php echo isset($xxx) ? $xxx : '';?>" />
    <?php };?>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
/*Formatierung für Fehlermeldung Login/Email*/
.wrapper #header #navline form .error {
    color: #F23;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 26px;
    padding:12px; 
    display: inline;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    line-height: 26px;
    right: 225px;  
    top: -4px;
}
.wrapper #header #navline form .error:before {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    left: 100%;
    width: 0px;
    top:-1px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 20px inset transparent;
    border-left: 20px dashed #f23;
    border-bottom: 20px inset transparent;
}

.wrapper #header #navline form .error:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    left: 100%;
    top:0px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 19px inset transparent;
    border-left: 18px dashed #fff;
    border-bottom: 19px inset transparent;
}
```

The problem I have is this now:

[image: problem 1]

and when echo another error:

[image: problem 2]

Comment: What has `php` got to do with this?

Comment: You should simply echo a single div and position that, then place any and all error message into that single div. If errors are positioned absolutely, there's no need for a separate div or class fo revery error, is there?

Comment: the errors will occure beside the input field. a simple div filled with all error messages is not an option.

Comment: hi!! bonny can you provide image if possible so that I can see what you want to accomplish

Comment: I would like to help but I miss some html.
When positioning an element absolute it relates to it's closest parent that does not have a static position.

Comment: hello, i updated the code and integetrated jsexperts code hints from the link. now i just have one error div with the triangle as a pseudoclass integrated. the further problem is the positioning. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this and take the triangle form there.
It will solve your issue.

http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: hello, thanks. this just converts the two divs (one for the error message and one for the triangle) into one. the positioning doesnt work as well. now there is a space between both plus the position is incorrect. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
.wrapper #header #navline form .errol {
color: #F23;
position: absolute;
z-index: 0;
height: 26px;
padding:8px; 
display: inline;
white-space: nowrap; 
line-height: 26px;
right: 100%;
top: 8%;
```

}

```
.wrapper #header #navline form .errol2 {
color: #FFF;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
height: 26px;
padding:8px; 
display: inline;
white-space: nowrap; 
line-height: 26px;
right: 100%;
top: 8%;
```

}